# AWS cross-account s3 bucket for Thanos

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, thanos

Is it possible to configure thanos sidecar to ingest logs to a s3 bucket in another aws account?
The use case is to centralise monitoring/observability to a single aws account.
I am trying it but i get "Access-denied" error in Thanos bucket and Thanos sidecar containers.

I am using prometheus operator on EKS.

Reference docs-
https://medium.com/zolo-engineering/configuring-prometheus-operator-helm-chart-with-aws-eks-c12fac3b671a

https://thanos.io/tip/thanos/storage.md/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/improving-ha-and-long-term-storage-for-prometheus-using-thanos-on-eks-with-s3/

Answer (score 0):

cross-account s3 bucket for thanos is possible.
I followed the first method "AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies and resource-based bucket policies" as mentioned in this article and it worked.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/